# How do I add a Thread to a controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to understand the threading process better. I have an application that delivers an email whenever a new item is created, works fine. I have been able to use `sleep`, in the create method, to delay the delivery.

I wanted to insert a thread and do a Client-side test. I received a `Template is missing` error when I added my initial thread to the create method.

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = @user.items.create(item_params)

    Thread.new do
      respond_to do |format|
        if @item.save
          format.html { redirect_to_user_path(@user), notice: 'Item was created successfully.' }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to_user_path(@user), notice: 'Item was NOT created successfully.' }
        end
       end

      PlayMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver

      @user.status = "Delivered"
      @user.save

      sleep 60
    end
  end

  private....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No-no-no-no. No. Don't do this.

You shouldn't use threads for this. As a matter of fact, in a rails app, you don't need to use threads **at all**.

Delayed emails need to be sent by background workers. You push emails onto a queue, then later worker (another process) picks the email and sends it.

Here's some links for you: [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for background jobs. [Action Mailer basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) guide.

> I have been able to use sleep, in the create method, to delay the delivery.

Delay delivery? Yes, in a sense. You also delayed whole response for that request, which precisely why we want to do delayed emails: to not slow down web requests.

Comment: Besides Sidekiq, you might consider [Sucker Punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch) if a job isn't mission critical (doesn't require guaranteed delivery).